# Edit Liquibase ChangeLog to include new changeset files at runtime

Tags: java, liquibase

I have a code which is editing the changelog.json at runtime. However when i run liquibase.migrate() it is not picking up the latest changes.

ChangeLog file before the runtime

```
{
  "databaseChangeLog" : [ ]
}
```

ChangeLog file during the runtime before execution of liquibase.update()

```
{
  "databaseChangeLog" : [ {
    "include" : {
      "file" : "changesets/myFolder/changeset-0.sql"
    }
  } ]
}
```

Method used to add new changeset files to ChangeSetLog at runtime

```
    public void addNewChangeSetToChangeLog(File file) throws IOException {
        FileReader fileReader= new FileReader("src/changesets/DbChangelog.json");
        BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        StringBuilder jsonString =new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            jsonString.append(line);
            jsonString.append("\n");
        }

        JsonNode jsonNode=objectMapper.readTree(String.valueOf(jsonString));
        ArrayNode arrayNode= (ArrayNode) jsonNode.get("databaseChangeLog");

        JsonNode newChangeSetNode=objectMapper.readTree("{\"include\":{\"file\":\""+file.getPath()+"\"}}");
        arrayNode.add(newChangeSetNode);

        objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        ObjectWriter writer = objectMapper.writer();
        writer.writeValue(new File("src/changesets/DbChangelog.json"), jsonNode);

        br.close();
        fileReader.close();
    }
```

I have tried

1. getting instance of liquibase class at runtime using class.getInstance()
2. Taking the location of ChangeLog at runtime via userinput so that it is unknown at compile time
   Following is method using to call liquibase update

```
public void execute(Connection connection) throws LiquibaseException, IOException {
        Database database = DatabaseFactory.
                getInstance().
                findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(connection));

        LiquibaseUtils liquibaseUtils=new LiquibaseUtils();

        liquibase.Liquibase liquibase = new liquibase.Liquibase("changesets/DbChangelog.json", new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database);

        liquibase.update(new Contexts(), new LabelExpression());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have an edited query for alter table or add/update data, you must declare it in new  , so when liquibase querying databasechangelog on your database, and it found new changeset, liquibase will execute it.

in your case, add new file include changeset-1.sql with new query.

Comment: I am not editing any existing changeset file. I am trying to create a new changeset file for any alter/add/update query and then add that file as the latest entry in by DbChangeLog.json. My exact issue is that it is not recognising changes to DbChangeLog.json at runtime

Comment: So let's say after run:1 i have 1 entry in my DbChangeLog. Liquibase is not executing any. After second run, i have 2 entries in my DbChangeLog, but liquibase only executed till first one.